# Whenever I try to load ghci via Homebrew, it crashes when it tries to load the integer-gmp package

Tags: haskell, homebrew, ghci

This is the exact error I'm getting.  Please note that I'm on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and using gcc version 4.9 installed via Homebrew.

```
shermmac:bin brandonsherman$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libgmp.dylib     
(dlopen(libgmp.dylib, 9): image not found)
```

How should I go about fixing this?  I uninstalled and reinstalled both ghc and haskell-platform already.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working for me.  I think not uninstalling `gmp` was what was making the uninstall and reinstall glitch for me.

```
brew uninstall ghc
brew uninstall haskell-platform
brew uninstall gmp
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install ghc
brew install haskell-platform
```